# How to set sinatra-authentication to use erb instead of haml?

Tags: authentication, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to set up the [sinatra-authentication](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication) gem in a simple sinatra app, and running into an issue where sinatra can't find the correct views.   I understand that sinatra-authentication uses haml by default, but I'm using erb in this app.

This in mind, I found [in the sinatra-authenticaiton docs that there is a setting which allows you to change the template engine](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication#overriding-default-views), by adding the following to your app file:

```
   configure do
       set :template_engine, :erb # for example
   end
```

I've added this to my app.rb file, and sinatra is still looking for the signup.haml when I try to hit the /signup route in my app.

A couple of notes:

1. I've included the gem in my Gemfile, and successfuly run a bundle install on my app.

   ```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'sinatra'
    gem 'data_mapper'

    gem 'pg'
    gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
    gem 'sinatra-authentication'
   ```
2. I saw something in the documentation that suggested that I may need to specify the location of my view files, so I added the following to my configuration block.

   ```
   set :sinatra_authentication_view_path, Pathname(__FILE__).dirname.expand_path + "views/"
   ```
3. **I think I've required the gem accurately in my app file by adding

   ```
   require "sinatra-authentication"

   use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'mys3cr3tk3y'
   ```

This gist is a current representation of my app.rb file in the root of my sinatra app.  https://gist.github.com/rriggin/5378641#file-gistfile1-txt

Here is a screenshot of the error sinatra throws:  http://cl.ly/image/0y041t0K3u3O

When I run the app locally, a 'dm-users' table is created in my local db as expected.

Is there another configuration setting that I'm missing in order to get sinatra-authentication to properly look for the erb templates rather than haml files.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[The specs don't test that the template_engine setting works](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/blob/master/spec/unit/user_specs.rb), and looking at [the way the setting is called](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/blob/master/lib/sinatra-authentication.rb#L24), I believe it's not correct, i.e.

```
send settings.template_engine, get_view_as_string("index.#{settings.template_engine}"), :layout => use_layout?
```

might better work as:

```
send app.settings.template_engine, get_view_as_string("index.#{app.settings.template_engine}"), :layout => use_layout?
```

that's what I reckon. If you fork the project, change the line and [add it to your Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/git.html) and it works then consider writing a quick spec for it and you'll have improved the mainline of that project as well as fixed your problem.